# Using browseForDoc() to define file path for saveAs() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I lurk this site all the time, but I think I have exhausted my options to find the info that I need.

I just want a button to trigger acrobat to run the browseForDoc() function, take the cPath the user selects and use that as the path for the saveAs() function. It seems like it should be easier than it has been. That is a folder-level script for adobe acrobat.

I get an error of "missing ; before statement 14". Besides that, it doesn't work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
//get windows user name
var getLoginName = app.trustedFunction(
    function(){
        //Get and return the user's login name
        app.beginPriv();
        return identity.loginName;
        app.EndPriv();
    }   
);

var fileExt = ".pdf";

var filePath = function(cFS, cPath, bPromptToOverwrite){
    this.cFS:cFS;
    this.cPath=cPath;
    this.bPromptToOverwrite=bPromptToOverwrite;
}

//Open save dialog,return user input values and saveas
var mySaveDialog = app.trustedFunction(
    function browse(cPath,oDoc){
        app.beginPriv();
        app.browseForDoc(){bSave: true, cFilenameInit: oDoc, cFSInit: ""};
        return this.cPath;
        var myPath = new filePath{cPath: browse.cPath};
        this.saveAs(myPath,myFile+fileExt);
        app.endPriv();
    }
);
```